# button.click() does not work under IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have created a jqx menu with the following script:

```
<ul style='width: 200px;'>
    <li onclick="logOffButton.click();">Sign off</li>
</ul>
```

So I'd like to trigger a click event on the "logOffButton" once the user clicked to the menu item. The code for the button:

```
<form id="logOff" action="www.example.com" method="get">
    <input type="button" id="logOffButton" placeholder="Are you sure you want to log off?" onclick="UserConfirm(this)" style="display: none;" />
</form>
```

So once the button click is triggered, it creates an JS alert message and if the user press OK it submits the form.

The problem is that while this works fine under Chrome and Firefox, it doesn't work under IE11.

The full code can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/82xhy/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:-

replace `<li onclick="logOffButton.click();">Sign off</li>` with

```
 <li onclick="$('#logOffButton').click();">Sign off</li>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/82xhy/4/)

Comment: Awesomeness! It works great! On the same web page I also use things like <li onclick="toCreateNewStand.submit();"> to submit forms, which has no problems with any of the browsers. Should I change it to match to the notation you provided, or are these fine?

Comment: you should change as may be this stop working some time

Answer (score 0):

Basically your code is wrong, and it works on chrome and other browsers because they try to understand what you mean. `logOffButton.click()` points to nothing, so ie being so bad and all does not understand what you mean. `$('#logOffButton').click();` or `document.getElementById('logOffButton');` will fix this problem because they both point exactly to where you need to, and don't require the browser to 'guess'

Both `$('#logOffButton')` and `document.getElementById('logOffButton');` are element selectors, first is jquery and second one is javascript.

Comment: Thanks I will change all these.